# What is corresponding solr type for cassandra type inet

Tags: solr, cassandra

I am using Datastax Enterprise 3.2. What is the corresponding field type of solr for cassandra type inet? Cannot find answer in official document.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in Solr. The backbone of Solr is Apache Lucene which it an "Information Retrieval" library.

Depending in your case, but I don't think you need to tokenise the IPs. If so, have a look at ***solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory***.

Keep in mind, Cassandra and Solr are totally different beasts. If Cassandra has a specific type, doesn't mean that Solr should have it also.

Comment: Actually I am asking a Datastax Enterprise specific question, not a general question on Cassandra and Solr.